Remove a repeated text watermark from a PDF
There's a PDF full of images. It doesn't have any text apart from the watermark itself.
Would appreciate any sort of help. Thanks in advance.

P.S The text is selectable, and is at the same position on every page. Adobe acrobat pro doesn't recognise this as a watermark, and given the pdf is huge, assume that uploading this pdf online isn't possible. I need a way to automate removing it for every page. I tried some simple pymupdf scripts using chatgpt, but I got nowhere:
import fitz

pdf_document = "Gravitation CJM21.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdf_document)

find_text = "PHYSICS"

for page_num in range(len(doc)):
    page = doc.load_page(page_num)
    text_instances = page.search_for(find_text, quads=True)
    for inst in text_instances:
        page.add_redact_annot(inst)
        page.apply_redactions()

doc.save("output.pdf")


Are you able to share a sample of the pdf?

@MarkusHirsimäki sure here's a sample that has 1 page: https://smallpdf.com/file#s=ab3768ad-4ea5-428d-9025-546396b0aedf

@KJ Thanks a lot for the file! Any suggestion on how I can do this myself, for the rest of the pdf?

I'm trying to find the second string using Hex Fiend, but I can't seem to find it

If the only text is the watermark, simply do page.add_redact_annot(page.rect) which will erase everything on page except what you exclude: page.apply_redactions(images=pymupdf.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_NONE, graphics=pymupdf.PDF_REDACT_LINE_ART_NONE). This will erase all text but leave images and vector graphics alone. Make sure to use doc.ez_save() to get rid of all the object "ghosts" left behind by applying redaction.

@KJ Thanks a ton man. I owe you big time. It worked! I need it only for printing so I'll skip the second part for now.

oh I see... I haven't tried JorjMcKie's method though

Of course my suggestion will lead to erasure of all text on the page. So if  - contrary to the statement - text is present beyond the "watermark" then that approach cannot be used. BTW I noticed OCR-ed text in the attached example page - so this may already yield the idea not applicable.
